# How to generically memoize any function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, memoization

I am trying to write a function to generically memoize any function in Ruby (as described in page 6 of this paper, which does the same thing in Python: http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.01/spring07/lectures/lecture4.pdf), but I am getting stuck. Here is my code, which doesn't work (the function is evaluated correctly, but not memoized). Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
def fib(n)
  return n if n<2
  fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
end

def memoize(&f)
  memo = {}
  doit = ->(arg) do
    return memo[arg] if memo[arg] 
    memo[arg] = f.call(arg)
    memo[arg]
  end
  doit
end

fib = memoize{|x| fib(x)}
puts fib.call(50)
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Be specific.

Comment: @Jordan: The function is not being memoized. If you ran the code this would be obvious.

Comment: Maybe so, but if you instead describe your problem clearly and explicitly to begin with, people won't have to run your code in order to figure out whether or not they can help you. I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fib` calls itself recursively and, by doing this, bypasses your memoization logic completely. Whatever approach you choose, you must overwrite the original definition of `fib`, to wrap memoization around it.

@Aetherus gave a working answer. Here is a more dynamic solution:

```
def fib(n)
  return n if n<2
  fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
end

def memoize(method_name)
  memo = {}
  old_fib = method(method_name)
  define_method(method_name) do |arg|
    return memo[arg] if memo[arg] 
    memo[arg] = old_fib.call(arg)
    memo[arg]
  end
end

memoize(:fib)

puts fib(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a method decorator pattern, [here](https://github.com/michaelfairley/method_decorators) is a sample implementation you can use as a library:

> ```
> require "method_decorators/memoize"
>
> class MyMath
>   extend MethodDecorators
>
>   +MethodDecorators::Memoize
>   def self.fib(n)
>     if n <= 1
>       1
>     else
>       fib(n - 1) * fib(n - 2)
>     end
>   end
> end
>
> puts MyMath.fib(200)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This can be useful if you landed here looking for a solution for lambdas:

```rb
fib = ->(memo, n) {
  return n if n < 2
  
  memo[n] ||= fib[n-1] + fib[n-2]
}.curry[Hash.new]

fib.(6)
```

a "debugging" version in case u want to visualize what is happening.

```rb
fib = ->(memo, n) {
  return n if n < 2
  
  memo[n] ||= begin
    puts 'calculating'
    fib[n-1] + fib[n-2]
  end
}.curry[Hash.new]
```

ps: requires ruby 2.5 or above
https://apidock.com/ruby/Proc/curry

Answer (score 0):

In python, functions are callable objects, and their names are just the names of the variables which store those objects, so you can just assign a new value to that variable to make the function functions totally different.

But in ruby, methods are not objects, their names are not variable names either. To override the original, you have to `def` it again.

Here is my solution:

```
def fib(n)
  return n if n<2
  fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
end

alias _fib fib

def fib(n)
  $memo ||= {}
  $memo[n] ||= _fib(n)
end

fib(50)  #=> 12586269025
```

I used the old ruby trick: make an alias and override the original. It's nasty (because there is an extra `_fib` after the overriding), but it's the easiest way doing this.

Comment: I'm not trying to override the original function, though. I want to pass the original function into another function that memoizes it.

Comment: The python code of `memoize` just returns a lambda (an anonymous function), and later it's assigned to the variable `fib`. The result is that the original `fib` is overridden.

Comment: True, but if I try something like `new_fib = memoize{|x| fib(x)}; puts new_fib(50)` I still have the same issue with the function not being memoized

Comment: @Eratosthenes: this is because you have `f.call(arg)` there. This transfers the control into the original `fib` method and it never returns to your memoization logic, because `fib` calls itself recursively. You _have_ to overwrite `fib` for this to work.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if you know how to do this, can you please show me your code?